# Why aren't cookies passed in a request from a sub-domain?

Tags: cookies, subdomain

Domain wide cookies are not passed in requests from a subdomain.

The cookie is originally set from www.mydomain.com.  I'm setting the cookie domain to ".mydomain.com" and the path to "/", so that the cookie will be available to my main domain and any subdomains.

```cs
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
    cookie.Domain = ".mydomain.com";
    cookie.Path = "/";
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    cookie.Secure = true;
    cookie.Values.Add("MyCookie", "Test Value");
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

The cookie gets sent back in any subsequent requests to www.mydomain.com, but requests from sub.mydomain.com do not include my cookie.

Comment: I was facing the exact same issue. My post is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56293528/javascript-cookies-not-working-on-sub-domains As you can see in the comments, you can try just pure one liner JavaScript: `document.cookie="yourvar=sumvalue; domain=.mydomain.com; path=/"` and add the other required parameters.